# Password Policy Windows API

Tags: c++, .net, winapi, policy

Is there any API to work with Local and/or Global Password Policy (read/write policy settings)?

I found there is a windows command:

> net accounts

What API does it use to read the settings? Is it possible to change the settings programmatically under admin permissions?

Answer (score 3):

Use can use the NetUserModalsGet() function in netapi32.lib.

See the example at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370656(VS.85).aspx

[**`NetUserModalsGet`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370656%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

```
struct USER_MODALS_INFO_0
{
    DWORD usrmod0_min_passwd_len;
    DWORD usrmod0_max_passwd_age;
    DWORD usrmod0_min_passwd_age
    DWORD usrmod0_force_logoff; 
    DWORD usrmod0_password_hist_len;
}
PUSER_MODALS_INFO_0 = ^USER_MODALS_INFO_0;    

PUSER_MODALS_INFO_0 info0;

NET_API_STATUS res = NetUserModalsGet(nil, 0,  out info0);

if (res <> NERR_Success)
   RaiseWin32Error(res);
try
   //Specifies the minimum allowable password length. 
   //Valid values for this element are zero through PWLEN.
   Log(info0.usrmod0_min_passwd_len);

   //Specifies, in seconds, the maximum allowable password age. 
   //A value of TIMEQ_FOREVER indicates that the password never expires. 
   //The minimum valid value for this element is ONE_DAY. 
   //The value specified must be greater than or equal to the value for the usrmod0_min_passwd_age member.
   Log(info0.usrmod0_max_passwd_age);

   //Specifies the minimum number of seconds that can elapse between the time
   //a password changes and when it can be changed again. 
   //A value of zero indicates that no delay is required between password updates. 
   //The value specified must be less than or equal to the value for the usrmod0_max_passwd_age member.
   Log(info0.usrmod0_min_passwd_age);

   //Specifies, in seconds, the amount of time between the end of the valid
   // logon time and the time when the user is forced to log off the network. 
   //A value of TIMEQ_FOREVER indicates that the user is never forced to log off. 
   //A value of zero indicates that the user will be forced to log off immediately when the valid logon time expires.
   Log(info0.usrmod0_force_logoff);

   //Specifies the length of password hi'+'story maintained. 
   //A new password cannot match any of the previous usrmod0_password_hist_len passwords. 
   //Valid values for this element are zero through DEF_MAX_PWHIST
   Log(info0.usrmod0_password_hist_len);
finally
   NetApiBufferFree(info0);
end;
```

Comment: @IanBoyd Can we use this NetUserModalsGet  to query Password Complexity?

Comment: @user3664223 NetUserModals doesn't have a way to check password complexity. What i did was use [**NetValidatePasswordPolicy**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/lmaccess/nf-lmaccess-netvalidatepasswordpolicy) using `NetValidatePasswordReset` semantics. Or you can read https://stackoverflow.com/a/31748252/12597 where someone says it is possible; but i didn't actually try to decipher it.

Answer (score -1):

You should have a look at:

[Windows-OS-User-Management](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18219/Windows-OS-User-Management)

[Query-the-New-Windows-Audit-Policies-Programmatica](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/61658/Query-the-New-Windows-Audit-Policies-Programmatica)

Comment: The first article is not related to Local/Global Password Policy. It sets user flags. I am looking for API to set at least Local Password Policy for a particular workstation. From the second article I do not understand what API I should use to change f.e. minimum password age or disable password complexity.