# DOMAIN_PASSWORD_INFORMATION Not able to retrieve

Tags: winapi, win32com, windows-kernel

I wanted to retrieve DOMAIN_PASSWORD_INFORMATION structure I can find [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ntsecapi/ns-ntsecapi-domain_password_information) documentation about this structure but not able find how to retrieve this information.
Any code sample help a lot.

Comment: It may be obsolete... `The MSV1_0_CHANGEPASSWORD_RESPONSE structure is obsolete.`

Comment: What do you want to retrieve? There is a [NetUserModalsGet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/lmaccess/nf-lmaccess-netusermodalsget) function which *retrieves global information for all users and global groups in the security database, which is the security accounts manager (SAM) database or, in the case of domain controllers, the Active Directory*. Also have a look at [Password Policy Windows API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13376262/password-policy-windows-api).

Comment: I was looking for password complexity